# Ignite Data streamer optimization

Tags: ignite

I am using below settings:

```
 allowOverwrite: false 
 nodeParallelOperations: 1 
 autoFlushFrequency: 10 
 perNodeBufferSize: 5000000
```

My records size is around 2000 bytes. And see the "grid-data-loader-flusher" 
thread stats as below:

Thread  Count   Average Longest Duration 
grid-data-loader-flusher-#100   38  4,737,793.579   30,427,862  180,036,156

What would be the best configurations for Data streamer?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem here? Actual performance, target performance, cluster configuration details.

Comment: Want to optimize Data streamer.

Comment: It is best to keep default settings unless you have any specific goals or bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

Its good to have parallel streaming mode for data streamer. You can achieve this by collecting you key-value records in java Map and call the streamer.addData() method in parallel mode over that map. Here is the snippet.

```
maptoStream.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(streamer::addData);
```

Also, if you are setting allowOverWrite to false then you cant use your custom stream receiver to process your collection of records. In this case it will skip the record(s) if it is already there in cache.
Regarding buffersize, you need to wait till buffer gets full each time to get it flushed automatically to cache. flush frequency comes to your rescue in this case and it will do periodic flushing. so whatever condition first satisfies(either buffer gets full or flush frequency reach) it will do flush. I preferred calling manual flush after above method call.
I observed that streamer works well with much more big collection on which you will call streamer.addData() method in parallel.

Comment: What about passing a map to addData()?

Comment: Yes,  you can do it by calling putAll on cache itself. It is even more faster.

Comment: Note that it is easy to get a deadlock when doing putAll() with hash map. My recommendation is on the DataStreamer.

Comment: Sure. I guess, we did not get answer for the question yet.

Comment: it really depends on your use cases. If you dont want to update existing key value pairs and want to achieve great speed then you van go ahead with alloqoverqrite=false config. If you want to use streamreciever (in case of update) then you carefully need  to choose several parameters to get good speed such as inline index size/ flush frequency/ checkpoint frequency/pagesize etc.